# How to Export the outlook profile

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, outlook

I have configure outlook as POP3, after 30 days the emails is deleted from server this setting i enabled in outlook.

Example this setting i did for user "A".

if user "A" pc if need to change/repair then once again i need configure the outlook as POP3 on new PC. I copied user "A" old outlook pst file to new pc and then i configure.

What problem i'm facing is that once again the old email downloading in old pst file, there are two problems happend emails duplication and taking time to download it depend upon how many MBs emails on server.

Is there any solution for the export profile or something which not download old emails in old pst.

Thanks
Basit.

Comment: The best solution would be to drop the antiquated POP3 protocol and use IMAP, or even better, the exchange protocol if the server is an Exchange server. No need to copy/backup profiles on every client, just click "next, next, next" on a new outlook and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop outlook downloading mail more than once from a server on POP, is to remove the mail from the server, which you've done.

It is just how the protocol works.

The solution would be to change to IMAP for this user, assuming the mail server supports it. This will Syncronise mail between the server and client, rather than simply copy the mail.

Comment: How this link https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1889-outlook-export-backup-profile.html

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not sure what you are asking with this link. Backing up the profile will not store the email. When using POP3/IMAP, email is only stored locally in a PST file.

it would help to know what kind of server you are connecting to (ISP email or Exchange server)